# Defining orthogonality in Banach Space

Tags: linear-algebra, banach-spaces

I am learning about Banach spaces and a question popped in my head. I have learnt that we can define orthogonality for vectors in inner product spaces, that is, $u, v$ orthogonal if:
$<u, v> = 0$.

I am wondering if we can define orthogonality in Banach spaces (or without completeness it is a normed space) in the following ways. $u, v$ orthogonal if:

1. $P_u(v) = 0$, that is, if the projection of $v$ onto $u$ is 0; or
2. $dist(v, span\{u\}) = ||v||$

My question is: is it possible to define orthogonality in Banach Spaces and will it be useful, and does my proposed definition make sense?

Thanks.

Comment: Your idea looks like it has some merit, but the more natural generalization of an inner product space is a Hilbert space (essentially a Banach space with an inner product)

Comment: For your first suggestion, $P_u$ isn't (uniquely) defined - you could already see that in $R^2$. I don't know about your second idea; it might help if you gave some more thought about what properties you want orthogonality to have.

Comment: How do you define the projection map? Your second definition is a reasonable one if you assume the unit ball is strictly convex.